# JSF/Primefaces data table f:setPropertyActionListener setting previous row's property

Tags: jsf, datatable, primefaces

I am using primefaces and JSF 2.0. I have a data table with a delete column that looks like this.

```
<p:column id="Delete" headerText="Delete">
<p:commandButton icon="delete" onclick="deleteConfirmation.show()" style="align:center">
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item}" target="#{controller.selectedItem}" /> </p:commandButton>

</p:column>
```

//Delete confirm dialog

```
<p:confirmDialog id="deleteConfirmDialog" message="Are you sure you want to delete?"
                header="Delete" severity="alert"
                widgetVar="deleteConfirmation">

<p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Yes"
                    update=":myList" oncomplete="deleteConfirmation.hide()"
                    actionListener="#{controller.delete}" />
                <p:commandButton id="cancel" value="No"
                    onclick="deleteConfirmation.hide()" type="button" />
            </p:confirmDialog>
```

Everything works great, except when i do filtering on the data table. After i filter and click delete, the selectedItem method gets the previous row in the data table( which is not part of filter result) instead of the current row.

This problem does not exist without filtering. 
I am using ViewScoped scope for my controller.

Any ideas on why this is happening? This seems like a basic thing that should be supported by a data table, so i am assuming that i am doing something wrong here. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its cause you are using pf version prior to 3.4 or you are not using the newly introduced in 3.3`filteredValue` attribute

This new feature was introduced cause of the following opened issue    [DataTable filtering problem and ActionSource Components](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3467)

Take a look at the showcase (that is using 3.4)

[DataTable - Filtering](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf;jsessionid=10266powr5y031bkv690jotq6c)

> DataTable filtering requires filteredValue reference in backing bean, for backwards compatibility if this reference is not defined, filtering will work using view state however this is a fallback and will be removed in future releases.

---

**Edit**

After reading your comment

> @Daniel- Thanks for the response.But upgrading to pf 3.4 helps partially. The correct row is deleted, but the data table does not refresh after the delete. If you notice i am updating the datatable as part of delete confirmation. Thoughts?

I got the following to say :

*Yup , its cause you probably not removing it from the list that is being referenced by the filteredValue attribute... (remove the row from that other list in case that the other list is not null) , weird solution? I think so too...* Although I can understand the logic behind the idea of executing the filtered list after we are in filter mode... but still...

take a look at the following forum thread I posted several days ago

[3.4 datatables execute of table affects filteredValue only?](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=24622)

feel free to post a rely there too :)

Comment: @Daniel- Thanks for the response.But upgrading to pf 3.4 helps partially. The correct row is deleted, but the data table does not refresh after the delete. If you notice i am updating the datatable as part of delete confirmation. Thoughts?

Comment: Yup , its cause you probably not removing it from the list that is being referenced by the `filteredValue` attribute... (remove the row from that other list in case that the other list is not null) , weird solution? I think so too...

Comment: It makes sense after you explain it. But i agree with you it should always fetch from value not filteredValue, because i am going back to the database to refresh my data table and that is not happening.

Comment: its cause you have to reload the list attached to the `filteredValue` too